# JScrollPane Not moving it stuck at one position

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

i am Painting some rectangles for class diagram making in a panel and that panel is in a JScrollPane i am updating panel's preferedSize according to size of my rectangle but when painting completes the JScrollPane does not move from its place and i am unable to visit my diagrams 
[image]

This is Code

```
        JPanel drawingPane = new DrawingPane();
        drawingPane.setBackground(Color.white);
scroller = new JScrollPane(drawingPane);
    scroller.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,200));
```

add(scroller,BorderLayout.CENTER);

**WHAT I AM DOING IN PAINT**

```
 Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(x, y, maxWidth+20, maxHeight+70);

        drawingPane.scrollRectToVisible(rect);
        drawingPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(x,y));
        drawingPane.revalidate();   
       g.drawRect(x, y, maxWidth+20, maxHeight+70);
```

Answer (score 0):

just removed `drawingPane.scrollRectToVisible(rect);` and everything gone ok